# 90s non-English spoken Demonology film from Europe; black mist, girl in a tub and guy at the library

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I come asking for your help because I want to know the name of a European horror film that I’ve been searching for almost three years and that nobody seems to know about. I believe that this movie was from someplace in Eastern or Central Europe, as it wasn’t spoken in English or in Spanish (my first language). I also believe that it was filmed by the end of the 90s, and I watched it in 2000 or 2001. The film seemed to be of high budget, unlike most of the 90s horror films with cheap special effects and photography (“Full Moon Features” movies-like), in general it seemed grim and with faint/dim light.

The story took place in some European city in the present day (for the movie) and the plot was about witchery and demonic beings. One of the main characters was a Caucasian man with knowledge of such kind, and he was a good guy.

There are only two scenes that I can recall from the film; I saw neither the beginning nor the ending of the whole movie.

The first scene that I remember consisted of two situations taking place at the same time: In the first situation there was a woman with blonde, short hair, who was likely the protagonist’s girlfriend, resting in a room and taking a shower in a white tub. Then, some kind of black mist started surrounding her very slowly, without her noticing this. After that, the camera changed to show us the main male character (the guy with knowledge of witches and demons), who was in the library doing some kind of research about Demonology. Then, he walked to the librarian, an unkempt and grim old man, to ask him for his phone so he could call a friend, but the librarian answered him in a rude way that he would not lend him his phone. However, because the good guy insists, the librarian agrees to angrily. Then, as the good guy spoke on the phone with his friend, there was a book about demons open on the table near the librarian, and he told his friend about an old lithograph about misty and dark demons covering the body of a woman, just exactly as it was happening with the girl from the other situation/scene. Also, while he was telling all this to his friend, the librarian looked at him in a mocking way and started smiling grimly but without making any noise (maybe he had something to do with the antagonists of the film).

In the other scene that I can remember the protagonist and his friend (the guy to whom he spoke to on the phone) were in a car going to a scary building in ruins where the demons and witches lived, who looked like young white women with dark hair and who were also wearing old black clothes. After that I don’t remember exactly what happened, but the protagonist’s friend stayed in the car, whereas the main guy decided to go into the house, but not before standing in front of a tall black gate with pentagrams on it. He had to rub his hands on those pentagrams in order to open the gate. Meanwhile, the other guy was still in the car trying to put a small crucifix inside a jar of holy water, which he managed to get stuck into the same jar. Then, as he tried to pull the crucifix out without success, some kind of demon with the looks of a robust black haired pale man and white eyes appeared behind the car, walking slowly towards it. Nevertheless, the guy with the crucifix didn’t notice him.

And that’s basically what I remember.

It is also worth mentioning that this movie is not any of the following:

- Constantine (2005)
- The Craft (1996)
- The Order (2003)
- The Ninth Gate (1999)
- End of Days (1999)
- Superstition (1982)
- Warlock (1989)
- I, Madman (1989)
- Listopad (1992)
- Necronomicon (1993)
- Subspecies (I'm pretty sure that wasn't a movie about vampires)
- La Setta (1991)

Comment: Could the film have been Asian? (Thanks for the detailed question, BTW)

Comment: Its like one of the episode of television series supernatural :)

Answer (score 3):

There was a Russian series of movies NightWatch, and the Sequel DayWatch.
About the forces of good and evil keeping each other in check.

Comment: Those are great movies (though the books are better), but from the descriptions given in the question, I very much doubt they're the answer.

Comment: while i enjoy these movies, these are definitely not the movie/s in question.